# Problem with auto-scrolling for mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I selected an option in the mat-select, the option-list scrolled to the end. The stream 
folkDistricts$ is set only at the beginning and does not change any more. I don't understand what the problem is

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>...</mat-label>

  <mat-select formControlName="folkDistrict" multiple>
    <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let folkdistrict of folkDistricts$ | async" [value]="folkdistrict.id">
        {{ folkDistricts.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Getting value from service:

```
this.folkDistricts$ = this.citiesService.folkDistricts(allCityIds);
```

Service:

```
  public folkDistricts(cityIds: number[]): Observable<IEntity[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/catalog/folk_districts`, {
      params: new HttpParams({
        fromObject: { 'cityIds[]': cityIds && cityIds.map(id => `${id}`) }
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with this. Can you provide any more information?

Comment: @AdamDunkerley I'm getting value from service:                          
   `this.folkDistricts$ = this.citiesService.folkDistricts(allCityIds);`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's trouble with Angular 7))

Comment: And what was the problem?